# FormView // ViewState interaction and ItemCommands

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle, formview

This is probably a page life cycle thing I'm not completely following, but I have the following problem.  I have a gridview object and a formview object.  When the gridview is clicked, the formview is populated.

When I am in formview inserting mode, everything works perfectly.  When I am in formview edit mode, the buttons do not reach the ItemCommand method.  I have tested this by adding a breakpoint to my code and every time, the save button from the insert method reaches the command but not the edit mode.

from the EditItemTemplate
    `<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CommandName="Update"
       Text="Save" meta:resourcekey="btnSaveResource2"  />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" 
       meta:resourcekey="btnCancelResource2" />`

From the InsertItemTemplate :
    `<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
    Text="Save" meta:resourcekey="btnAddResource1"  />
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" 
              meta:resourcekey="btnCancelResource3" />`

FormView
    `<asp:FormView ID="poolEditFV" runat="server" OnItemCommand="poolEditFV_ItemCommand"
                    EnableViewState = "False" OnModeChanging="poolEditFV_ModeChange"
                    meta:resourcekey="poolEditFVResource1">`

Now, I don't really want the items in this form in the ViewState, but I tried enabling the view state anyhow.  When I enable it, the ItemCommand method is properly reached.  However... if I clicked edit, cancel, edit, I get a huge ViewState error (probably because my FormView is being updated programmatically in the middle of the page's lifecycle).

Can anyone offer me some help on this one?  I don't know how to get the edit items to actually fire commands unless I use the ViewState (which I don't really want to) and that creates errors of its own.

Thank you.